# How do I jump to an arbitrary scene in a complex storyboard from a push notification?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, push-notification, uistoryboard

Let's say I have a relatively complex storyboard with a login screen guarding access to a UITabBarController containing a couple of embedded UINavigationControllers and their children, like so:

[image: A moderately complex storyboard]

The LoginViewController is the root VC, and decides if the user is logged in, either by checking stored credentials or asking for fresh ones. It then presents the UITabBarController as a modal.

There are four scenarios:

1) If the user starts the app from cold, they should see the ListViewController.

2) If the app is started from cold via a push notification regarding a "Foo", they should go directly to the FooDetailViewController.

3) If the app is warm-started via a push notification regarding a "Foo", they should go directly to the FooDetailViewController, no matter what VC they were looking at when the app was backgrounded.

4) If the user warm-starts the app, they should go back to whatever VC they were looking at when the app was backgrounded.

Where does the logic for all of this decision-making go? If I put it in the AppDelegate, I end up trying to push view controllers onto my hierarchy before they exist (`Warning: Attempt to present ViewControllerX on ViewControllerY whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`). The UITabBarController's viewWillAppear: lifecycle method does not seem to be being called on a warm start, and putting logic in *every* child view controller to check if it's been started from a push seems like coupling things that shouldn't be coupled (and in practice seems to lead to corrupted navigation stacks.)

How does everyone else structure this?

Answer (score 0):

You must create that logic inside `UIApplicationDelegate` by creating properties needed to decide what is the view controller that has to be opened first.

The first place you have that guarantees the user interface (the window) is ready, is on the application delegate's `-applicationDidBecomeActive:`, but from here there are two courses of action:

- For `ListViewController` and `OtherListViewController` is easy, you can just call `-setSelectedViewController` on `UITabBarController`;
- For FooDetail and BarDetail, I think the best method is putting some logic on ListViewController, sending it a reference to the object you want to show the detail and by performing the relevant segue on ListViewController's `-viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: This will not instantiate the correct navigation hierarchy though.

Comment: Oh, I see, I didn't understand that he needs the same hierarchy. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, there are many subtleties. It's a good tip that the window is ready in applicationDidBecomeActive, but when is that called relative to application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:? And this really only covers case 1 and 2; if the user backgrounds the app from OtherListViewController, I would have to have logic in it to check if I'd woken from a push, then setSelectedViewController on the tab bar, then pass off to the logic that called the correct segue to FooDetailVC. And should this happen in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear?

Comment: I suggest `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` because it gets called regardless of the app coming from an inactive state or background state. But the logic of it all will be in several places, like `-application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`, to cover the case of push notification. In case 3, you can recreate the storyboard, so you have more control of the flow. In case 4, use state restoration.